# Displaying or Hiding Metadata on Page from WP CPanel

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "Celeb". This CPT contains two Taxonomy terms as "Men" and "Women".Each Post has two metadata as "Name" and "Age".

[image]

Now I would Like to add a "Visibility" checkbox to WordPress CPanel to enable or disabe displaying the "Age" metadata on the page based on the Terms.
For example I would like to Hide the Age for all post under the  ONLY "Women" Taxonomy term when the checkbox has been checked or vice versa.Can you please let me know how I can do this?

---

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a WordPress CPanel?

Comment: Is there any one to help me on this?

Comment: Not unless you explain what a WordPress CPanel is, are you referring to the post section in the WordPress admin (cPanel is a software company unrelated to WordPress).

Comment: Hi Wyck, sorry for the confusion! I mean the Dashboard for Taxonomy by Cpanel! Can you please take a look at updated images above? I tried to ilustrate what I mean by this post.Thanks